# Incompatible operand types char and string - JAVA

Tags: java, string

The program compares a character to a String and counts the number of times that character repeats in the String. Line 8 gives error "Incompatible operand types char and string" I can't seem to figure out a way around this error:

```
    Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter a word: " );
    String word = input.next();
    System.out.println("enter a letter: ");
    String letter = input.next();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < word.length(); i++)
        if(word.charAt(i) == letter)
            count++;
```

Comment: What does `charAt` returns? What is the datatype of letter?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you can't compare a String with a char, same as you can't compare a car with a potato.

Answer (score 1):

You can not compare a char with a string. So you should modify the *if* part like this:

```java
    if(word.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is not a `char`. `letter` is a `String`.

Just test if `word.indexOf(letter)` is not -1. And prior to this you want to test whether `letter` has length 1.